# from_with tag causing internal server error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, form-with

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and am following the online tutorial here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

As soon as I try to implement a 'form_with' element I get the following error in the terminal:

Started GET "/articles/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-04-22 12:57:00 +0930
Processing by ArticlesController#new as HTML
  Rendered articles/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

I've been able to complete the tutorial successfully up until this stage, which has included making controllers, views and routing. Up until this point I've been able to access the pages in my browser no problems. I've tried searching but can't seem to find an explanation online. I'm running rails using Ubuntu on my Windows laptop.

If anyone can point out the issue or forward me somewhere that does I'd be super grateful!

Tips on how to debug would also be helpful, so far this is the only message printing to the terminal which seems rather ambiguous.

UPDATE

I read of others having issues running rails on Windows so I tried to attempt the same process on Ubuntu running within a virtual machine but I'm getting the same problem. Could this be a versions issue? I updated my rails to version 4.2, ruby is still version 2.5.1

I really want to get moving and this problem is taking a lot of time, any help is super appreciated !

Comment: That's not the error, that's just the html status code. There should be an error and a stack trace above that. You can also check at your app's log folder, there should be something there

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the log file, I checked and the only other information given I just edited in above, any recommendation on how to hone in on the issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure why rails is not writing the complete error info, check this guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels and make sure you have the correct log level and logger config

Comment: Ensured the log level was set correctly - I also tried running on Ubuntu but the same problem occurs ...

Comment: I have the exact same problem on Ubuntu. There is no extra info, no stack trace, besides what it's stated in this question.

Comment: My ruby versions are:  Ruby 2.5.1p57, Rails 4.2.10

Answer (score 0):

I got pass the problem by installing a newer rails: 5.1

Ubuntu:

```
sudo gem install rails --version=5.1
```

However, the already created "blog" tutorial project preserved its rails version. I end up deleting the "blog" directory and starting the whole process over.